# Using Regex in Vim movement

Tags: vim, regular-expression, cursor

Is there any way to use a regular expression for moving in Vim?

For example, I want to move my cursor to the first occurrence of the pattern `abc`.

Can I do something analogous to `fa` but replacing the character `a` with a pattern? And can I use regular expressions with the `t` and `f` commands?

Comment: You can search with regex and the cursor will move to the start of the regex.  Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 3):

As stated in a comment by Sardathrion, you can search to navigate. This is actually too useful in Vim to ignore. A few tips regarding search to navigate:

- Use <kbd>/</kbd> to search forward, <kbd>?</kbd> to search backward.
- You may want to turn on [`incsearch`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27incsearch%27) so that Vim will jump to matches as you type. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> when you are at the location you want.
- You may also want to turn on search highlight with [`hlsearch`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27hlsearch%27).
- After arriving at the location you want, you can use [`nohlsearch`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#%3anohlsearch) to disable the highlight. It will be enabled again when you do the next search.
- If you find yourself using lots of regex consider using [`\v` ("very magic")](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5Cv).